# Template locked block does not show appender

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I have a parent block and a child block. When the parent block is chosen the child block should show the appender button so the user can click on it and choose any block. They should be able to delete what they add but not the actual child block. When I try to use template lock the appender never appears, just a thin blue line which I can't interact with.

The parent

```
  <InnerBlocks
    allowedBlocks={["myblocks/single"]}
    renderAppender={false}
  />
```

The child

```
      <InnerBlocks
        templateLock="all"
        renderAppender={InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender}
      />
```